# Cost error in booking confirmation

Tags: bookings

In March this year, I booked 1 hotel room for 3 nights in Colombo, Sri Lanka through booking.com after browsing their website and entering the required data: 1 room ; 3 nights and got a price offer of Rs.28,676 (excl. taxes). I assumed it was the total price for 3 nights since "per night" was not mentioned and booked the room.

Booking.com's booking confirmation also stated 1 room/3 nights Rs.28,676.

However, at check-out at the hotel, I was forced to pay three times the amount. The fault is booking.com's due to insufficient information.
What can I do. Booking.com is not replying to my e-mails on this issue.

Comment: When I look on Booking.com I see prices as given as the total for the stay, verified by looking at prices for 2 nights, 3 nights, 4 nights. Is it possible that the hotel in question is at fault here?

Answer (score 1):

You should call Booking.com on their phone, I've heard they're responsive.

Comment: While this may work, and I do indeed hope that it does for the OP, it's not acceptable for emails to be ignored. When we're travelling phone calls may be expensive or impractical. Asynch communication via email is often much more useful.